# Gnome locks screen on Super+L, can't disable it

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

So apparently Gnome has changed the default shortcut for Lock screen to `Super+L`. That's fine by me, but I want to disable it and replace it with something else.

So I open the Keyboard->Shortcuts->System settings, where it claims that Ctrl+Alt+L is bound to locking screen. But when I press Super+L, I still get locked.

I then reassigned Super+L to Typing->Switch to next source. But I still get locked out on Super+L! Why is this and what to I do about it?

Comment: After changing the shortcut, try logging out. I changed the short cut and them logged out of the current user. I looged back in and now Super+L is no longer locking my screen. I am using Ubuntu-Gnome 16.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventhough there's only one shortcut/keybinding listed in `Keyboard->Shortcuts->Systems` there may actually be more than one. If changing it the usual way doesn't work (after rebooting), I'd try opening a terminal and typing `dconf-editor` which brings up a graphical interface with lots of "hidden" settings. The setting you're looking for is `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/screensaver` which locks the screen and by default is mapped to `<Super>l`.